# Create custom permission classes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rbac

I have designed my own `RBAC system` for my Django app. Unlike the original Django's role-based that uses only `permissions`, `content_types`, `groups`, and `users` table, I designed mine so that it includes a model for defined `operations` (i.e. `read, write, print`), the `objects` (i.e. `Post, Events, Documents`), the `roles` (`Writer Level 1, Events Manager`) and the necessary relationships i.e. my own permissions table which takes in the `object reference` and a matching `operation reference` (i.e. `Post | add`).

My problem now is I am not quite sure how to implement this in `DRF`. When I use `permission_class = (DjangoObjectPermissions,)` and someone sends a 'POST' request to the `Post` model/table, we all know Django will check if the user has `Can add post` permission. I want to do this as well but I want Django to refer to my RBAC models/tables.

I want to write my own permission classes in my `permissions.py` but I might need a bit hint on how to implement this.

I've read you can [create custom permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), but I am not sure if that also means you can enforce your own RBAC tables with it.

Answer (score 3):

Alright after checking `rest_frameworks`' `permissions.py`, I think I can enforce my own permission class behavior this way:

1. Create a custom permission class that subclasses `rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission`
2. override `has_object_permission()` method
3. Inside the method, write a logic that maps the requesting user into my custom RBAC models to check whether or not he has given the appropriate permission
4. Return the appropriate boolean

Answer (score 1):

According to the [DRF Permissions doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions)

> As with **`DjangoModelPermissions`**, this permission must only be applied to views that have a **`.queryset`** property or **`.get_queryset()`** method. Authorization will only be granted if the user is authenticated and has the relevant per-object permissions and relevant model permissions assigned.

So, you should define either **`queryset`** attribute or **`get_queryset(...)`** method in your view class.
Example:

```
class MyViewClass(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    ...
    ...
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SomeModel.objects.filter(some_field='foo')

    ...
    ...
    ...
```

The permissions to a User or groups can be controlled via [Django's Admin site as well as Django shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)

Comment: This is great but I do not intend to use Django's built-in group-based or role-based permission. I have designed my own RBAC model structure that utilizes additional custom models like modules, operations/actions, objects...... That said, the only way I can think of is to design my own permission class... Problem is I am not sure where to start....